# MySQL . Combine records from one table with another table with not common field

Tags: mysql

tired of searching for a solution to this:

```
Table A
-------
RED
BLUE
YELLOW

Table B
-------
BALL
CUBE
STICK
```

Need this result:

```
RED BALL
RED CUBE
RED STICK
BLUE BALL
BLUE CUBE
BLUE STICK
YELLOW BALL
YELLOW CUBE
YELLOW STICK
```

It is possible to get this in one query?

Comment: This is very tersely worded. Do your tables have just one column each as shown, or are you wanting to join all the columns in each and you're just showing one? Regardless, some form of `cross join` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * From TableA Cross Join TableB